# OutOfMemoryError in my app using Universal Image Loader

Tags: android, image, out-of-memory, loader, universal

can you help me? I using universal-image-loader-1.9.1-with-sources.jar in my app,This app has too much images and these images have little bigger. the setting of ImageLoaderConfiguration is

```
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
          .threadPoolSize(3)
          .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2)
          .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
          .memoryCache(new UsingFreqLimitedMemoryCache(30 * 1024 * 1024))
          .discCacheFileCount(100)
          .discCacheSize(50 * 1024 * 1024)
          .discCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(createCacheDir()))
          .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO)
          .writeDebugLogs() 
          .build();
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);

  options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .showStubImage(R.drawable.default_small) 
        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.default_small) 
        .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.default_small) 
        .cacheInMemory(true) 
        .cacheOnDisc(true) 
        .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT)
        .bitmapConfig(Config.RGB_565)
        .build();

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    AnimateFirstDisplayListener a = new AnimateFirstDisplayListener();
    List<String> list = a.displayedImages;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        MemoryCacheUtil.removeFromCache(list.get(i),imageLoader.getMemoryCache());                                           
    }
    imageLoader.clearMemoryCache();
    imageLoader.clearDiscCache();
    AnimateFirstDisplayListener.clearUrl();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

onbackpress this method are useless

Comment: wish you a very happpy new yaer ,please accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the info in the [Usefull info section](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader#useful-info) ?

You should also try to use

ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_POWER_OF_2

ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT will be automatically rounded down to a power of 2 by the BitmapFactory.
In this case, if the UIL library compute a needed scale of 3, the image will be scaled only by 2, leading to possible OOM errors.